# Grabbing ID of the user that reacted to a message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I got this part of my code:

```js
message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id != message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '✅' || reaction.emoji.name == ''),
    { max: 1, time: 2147483647 }).then(collected => {


if (collected.first().emoji.name == '✅') {
    message.delete()
    client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send(BufferClear);
```

What it does: bot sends an embed, then if user reacts with `✅` it sends `BufferClear`, question is, how do I get the ID of the user that reacted to the message?

Answer (score 1):

In `awaitReactions()` you have 2 parameters, one of which is `user`, so you can use `user.id` to get that user's ID.